# Open pdf in windows 8 store apps(C#) using foxit reader SDK

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

How to open pdf file in windows 8 store apps(C#) using Foxit reader SDK or suggest me any of free library to open pdf files in windows 8 store apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support windows RT, then you can go for iTextSharp(its free),
and if you want to support windows RT then there is no free library for C#, you might prefer to code your apps using HTML5 and Javascript and use Mozilla's pdf.js to read PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

The Foxit SDK has support for UWP development. If I look into samples there is whole demo viewer UWP sample code.